# How can implement First_value and Last_Value SQL functions in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch JavaAPI supports the AggregationBuilder for sum, min, max, avg, and count. So what about First/First_value and Last/Last_value how can implement these functions.

Here is the reference to the documentation, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_metrics_aggregations.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use an aggregator for your Elasticsearch query

```
"aggs": {
   "FIRST_VALUE": {
      "top_hits": {
         "size": 1,
         "sort": [
            {
               //The string below measures or assess which among the column would you like to arrange in order, 
               //for this example, we presume that there's a "my_date" field in your index
               "my_date": {
                  "order": "asc"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "LAST_VALUE": {
      "top_hits": {
         "size": 1,
         "sort": [
            {
               "my_date": {
                  "order": "desc"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using the serialize method to generate the JSON file, I am looking for APIs like AggregationBuilder for implementing last and first